# Add operator to native classes

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I recently began to learn Ruby and I saw following way to format a string:

```
"%d"        % 123         #=> "123"
"%08b %02x" % [15, 15]    #=> "00001111 0f"
```

Is there a way to realize this in C#? I tried a lot, but all attempts failed. Here is a example of one of my attempts:

```
public static string operator % (string format, IFormatable[] items) {
    for (int n = 0; n < items.Length; n++) format.Replace("%" + n, items[n].ToString());
    return format;
}

"%0 %1" % new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" } // Expected result => "Foo Bar"
```

I know the Methods like ToString() and PadLeft(), but I wanted to find out, if the so-called Method Extensions also work for operators.

Comment: How are you adding this stuff to `string`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly? You can already do `string.Format("{0} {1}", new [] {"Foo", "Bar"});`. Most of the "special" operators you want to implement are probably already implemented in an other easier way. If you want to add other functionality to a class look for extension methods.

Comment: I don't "add" the stuff to string. I use Extension Methods (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx); I haven't a concrete reason for trying this. I simply wanted to test, if this works :)

Comment: Why not using python then?

Comment: I don't c# but this what you want http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Between the method [`Convert.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kwkfdz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which:

> Converts the value of a 16-bit signed integer to its equivalent string
>   representation in a specified base.

and the [`ToString()` formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided, you have all of the functionality you are looking for.  You can also use [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to add 0's to the left.

```
int num = 15;
string binNum = Convert.ToString(num, 2).PadLeft(8,'0'); // value 00001111
string hexNum = Convert.ToString(num, 16).PadLeft(2, '0'); // value 0f
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I know these functions. I read something about putting a "this" before the first parameter of a method to make it a Extension Method. So I wanted to try, if this also works with operators. And that's the topic of my question. Sorry if this was not clear.